# Django syncdb trying to insert duplicate rows when multiple databases are specified

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-syncdb, django-orm

I'm in the process of configuring my Django app for multiple databases, and as a stop-gap measure, I'm using the following configuration in my settings.py:

```
READ_DATABASE = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'thedatabase',
    'USER': 'read_only',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB'
    }
}

WRITE_DATABASE = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'thedatabase',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB'
    }
}

DATABASES = {'default': WRITE_DATABASE,
             'read': READ_DATABASE}
```

These point to the same database, in order to emulate a master-slave pair. The `read_only` user, as you might guess, only has read permissions.

My database router looks like this:

```
from django.conf import settings 

class MasterSlaveRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'read' 

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default' 

    def allow_relation(self, db1, db2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return db in ('default',)
```

When running syncdb, it now crashes immediately after setting up the superuser, with the error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'auth-permission' for key 'app_label'")
```

The offending SQL that's failing to execute is:

```
INSERT INTO `django_content_type` (`name`, `app_label`, `model`) VALUES (permission, auth, permission)
```

This error **only** occurs when the second read database is sepcified in my `settings.py`, when only a `default` database is present, the syncdb command completes successfully.

Any suggestions what could be causing this?

**Edit:** Django version is 1.2.3

Comment: How do you specify `DATABASE_ROUTERS`? It looks like `post_syncdb` has been triggered twice.

Comment: `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MasterSlaveRouter']` is in my config file.

Comment: OK, can you show the actual `path.to`;and try to put `MasterSlaveRouter` inside settings and then set `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['settings.MasterSlaveRouter']`?

Comment: The router is definitely being hit - I have added `import pdb; pdb.set_trace` to the `db_for_read/write` methods verify this. The breakpoints are being hit and the discoverability of the router is definitely not the problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yes, I do not mean its not been used. I mean the importing might cause the `post_syncdb` be bound more than once thus contenttypes wants to generate content_type for Permission model twice times, thus the error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've now solved the problem, detailed below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours of tinkering, I've deduced that the reason this was occurring is because some Django models (in this case `django.contrib.contenttype.models.ContentType`, but also `django.contrib.site.models.Site`) have their own [inbuilt caching mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttypemanager).

Since I have set up two different connections to the same database, this was causing a problem since the `contenttype` cache for the read-only connection was not being invalidated by a write to a `ContentType` model on the write connection.

The solution to this was to change my `db_for_read` method to something like this:

```
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in ('contenttypes', 'sites'):
            return 'write'
        else:
            return 'read'
```